Cannot Log Into Samba DC with Domain Credentials
Cannot Log Into Samba DC with Domain Credentials
I am experimenting with Samba for Active Directory, and everything seems to be working just fine except the fact I cannot log into the domain controller with domain credentials. I have scoured the web, and I have only managed to find a couple similar issues, but neither of them had a working solution. I would appreciate some assistance in getting this figured out. Here are some details:
/etc/krb5.conf (copied from /var/lib/samba/private/krb5.conf after domain provisioning per Samba documentation)
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN.LAB
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
DOMAIN.LAB = {
        default_domain = domain.lab
}

[domain_realm]
        DC1 = DOMAIN.LAB

/etc/samba/smb.conf as generated by Samba during privisioning
# Global parameters
[global]
        netbios name = DC1
        realm = DOMAIN.LAB
        server role = active directory domain controller
        server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbindd, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/domain.lab/scripts
        read only = No

/etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         files systemd winbind
group:          files systemd winbind
shadow:         files systemd
gshadow:        files systemd

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis

Testing account credentials works fine:
root@DC1:/etc# kinit administrator
Password for administrator@DOMAIN.LAB:
Warning: Your password will expire in 36 days on Sun 20 Oct 2024 03:09:00 PM MDT
root@DC1:/etc# klist -a
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: administrator@DOMAIN.LAB

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/13/2024 16:16:05  09/14/2024 02:16:05  krbtgt/DOMAIN.LAB@DOMAIN.LAB
        renew until 09/14/2024 16:16:00
        Addresses: (none)
root@DC1:/etc#

But authentication still fails, and the SSH journal shows:
root@DC1:/etc# journalctl -fu ssh
...
Sep 13 16:20:35 DC1 sshd[4513]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.10.10.10  user=administrator
Sep 13 16:20:37 DC1 sshd[4513]: Failed password for administrator from 10.10.10.10 port 45530 ssh2
Sep 13 16:20:38 DC1 sshd[4513]: Connection closed by authenticating user administrator 10.10.10.10 port 45530 [preauth]

Again, I would appreciate any assistance with getting this figured out. Please let me know if there are any additional details needed to assist, and I will add those. I am banging my head on the desk with this one.
Thank you in advance!!
EDIT: I just tried logging into the console, and still no go.
The strange thing is, the username seems to be recognized, because the SSH journal says Failed password for administrator, but I am 110% confident the password is correct (I can log into any other domain member with the same creds). If I try an account I know does not exist, it says Failed password for invalid user foobar. The fact it recognizes an invalid/non-existent user, but says Failed password for a valid user, puzzles me.

What about a console logon?

Good question. Just tried, and still no. I can only log in with local accounts.
